# Having trouble catching an exception in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Working with Python 3.7.3, still figuring out how exception handling works.

I'm writing an xmpp bot, using slixmpp. I'm trying to make it so that if it loses connection to the server, it will try to reconnect. There doesn't seem to be any way to do this built in to slixmpp, so I'm write something into my own code to do it.

I've imported slixmpp as xmpp, and using it's send_raw() method to test that we're still connected to the server.

```
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)  # Send every 5 seconds just for testing purposes
        xmpp.send_raw('aroo?')
```

When I sever the connection to the server, this is what it spits out:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "testcom.py", line 19, in run
        eval(self.thing)()
      File "testcom.py", line 28, in check_conn
        xmpp.send_raw('aroo?')
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\slixmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 926, in send_raw
        raise NotConnectedError
    slixmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream.NotConnectedError
```

I'm assuming that "NotConnectedError" is the exception that I need to catch, so I put the code inside a try block, like so:

```
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)  # Send every 5 seconds just for testing purposes
            xmpp.send_raw('aroo?')
    except NotConnectedError:
        # Do a thing
        pass
```

And this is what I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File   "testcom.py", line 28, in check_conn
        xmpp.send_raw('aroo?')
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\slixmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 926, in send_raw
        raise NotConnectedError()
    slixmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream.NotConnectedError                                                                                             

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      "testcom.py", line 19, in run
        eval(self.thing)()
      File "testcom.py", line 29, in check_conn
        except NotConnectedError:
    NameError: name 'NotConnectedError' is not defined
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your imports but make sure you have `from slixmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream import NotConnectedError` otherwise it doesn't have a definition for `NotConnectedError` within the application. You could also change `NotConnectedError` to `xmpp.xmlstream.xmlstream.NotConnectedError` if you don't want to have it imported as well.

Comment: That did it! I added the extra import and it's working perfectly. Thanks!